# How to test Hikaricp connection integrated with tomcat 9?

Tags: java, hikaricp, tomcat9

I'm using Hikaricp : 4.0.3 integrated in Tomcat 9. I have made changes in tomcat context.xml and added hikari jar to tomcat/lib. On running my application on local, my application is up but don't know if the hikari pool is working or not. So can anyone please help to know how to test the hikari connection pool on local ??

Comment: To test a datasource you run some validation query like `SELECT 1`. Most datasources do it when you call `DataSource#getConnection()`.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr P. Karwasz for the info. Also can you please help to know where we can see output of the test query? I have added 'SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1' as testQuery for ibm db2, but then where to see its output? I have run my application on local will i see it in the console logs there ?

Comment: The results of `connectionTestQuery` are used internally. Where do you want to test if the pool is working? From your code? Or from an external monitoring tool? Hikari can register MBeans that can be followed using JMX (e.g. `jconsole`). Just set `registerMbeans` to true.

Comment: Yes test from my code on local.